# Fix positioning div by jQuery / Javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

As you may know, fixed positioning is not compatible in most mobile devices. As a workaround, I would like fix positioning on a div using Javascript (jQuery would be nicer) with no `position: fixed`.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could in the scroll event reset the position of the div to keep it where it is.

Comment: It wouldn't be very easy. You would have to use "position: absolute". But for it to act like "fixed", the only parent element on the page that would be able to have the style "position" defined would be the body tag. If any other element had "position" defined, your target element would be positioned based on that, not the body. If that's possible, you can bind the window's "scroll" event and set the element's top & left based on the scrollTop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look to JQuery plugins; a quick search found these:

- http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll
- http://chrisiona.com/fixedposition/
- http://www.gregjopa.com/2011/07/conditional-fixed-positioning-with-jquery/

I'm sure there are plenty others.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html). It simulates the effect using `absolute` positioning and updating the position each time the page is scrolled.

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use vanilla JavaScript. Here's an example script that keeps a `div` with an ID `fixedDiv` on the top of the page:

```
var fixedDiv = document.getElementById("fixedDiv");
window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrolltop = window.pageYOffset;
    fixedDiv.style.top = scrolltop + "px";
};
```

CSS:

```
#fixedDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I've used [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) in the past and it worked well in all mobile browsers aswell as the desktop browsers.